# Hessian matrix of vectorized matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, derivations, hessian

I need to find the Hessian Matrix of $f(X,Y) = C \operatorname{vec} (A X^{-1} Y)$ where $C$ and $A$ are constant matrices and $X$ and $Y$ are the variable matrices. This would be a vector function of matrices.

I did manage to find an expression for the first differential which is

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{d} f(X,Y) &= C (Y' \otimes A) \operatorname{d} \operatorname{vec} (X^{-1}) + C (I \otimes A X^{-1}) \operatorname{d} \operatorname{vec} (Y) \\
&= - C (Y' \otimes A) ((X^{-1})' \otimes X^{-1}) \operatorname{d} \operatorname{vec} (X) + C (I \otimes A X^{-1}) \operatorname{d} \text{vec} (Y)
\end{align*}

but I am stuck with regards to the second differential because I am not sure how to proceed with Kronecker products.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I you write `C\operatorname{vec}A` instead of `C\text{vec}A`, then you see $C\operatorname{vec}A$ instead of $C\text{vec}A$, and if you write `C\operatorname{vec}(A)` instead of `C\text{vec}(A)` then you see $C\operatorname{vec}(A)$ instead of $C\text{vec}(A).$ with `\operatorname`, the horizontal space to the right and left of $\operatorname{vec}$ depends on the context.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'd say that the question is a bit ill posed in the sense that "Hessian matrix" somehow assumes that the input of $f$ is a vector and the output is a scalar. Here you have two matrices as input and another matrix as output and the notion of "Hessian matrix" does not really makes sense. In general the Hessian of a scalar valued function $f$ is a matrix representation of the second derivative $f$ (which is a bilinear form the product of the domain of definition of $f$ with itself).

Comment: Here you don't even have a scalar valued function. For $f:X\to Y$ for linear spaces $X,Y$, the second derivative of $f$ is a bilinear form from $X\times X$ to $Y$.

Answer (score -1):

$\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial X^2}:(H_1,H_2)\mapsto C(vec(AX^{-1}H_2X^{-1}H_1X^{-1}Y)+vec(AX^{-1}H_1X^{-1}H_2X^{-1}Y))$;

$\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{{\partial X}{\partial Y}}:(H,K)\mapsto -Cvec(AX^{-1}HX^{-1}K)$.

$\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial Y^2}:(K_1,K_2)\mapsto 0$.